# Problem with creating a branch in atlassian-sourcetree

Tags: frontend, atlassian-sourcetree

I am fairly new to SourceTree, so apologies if this question appears stupid... I have much more experience from VSC, but I think SourceTree works in a different way. I use SourceTree under Windows 10. The central repository is at bitbucket.org.

I have failed for creating a new branch. I added SSH key and cloning repositories locally, this did work good but I have faced with this problem.  All help will be appreciated.

`git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks branch`
`fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue and just wanted to let you guys know if anyone else having a problem with this one. When I tried to pull working copy of master, SourceTree was creating a `.git/index.lock` file. But this file was already existed for me.

Solution is, remove it and try to pull or create a new branch again.

So go to start and open git bash, use following command;

```
$ rm .git/index.lock
```

TA DA!

Open SourceTree again, pull or create a new branch. It should work now.